# The parameter can't have a value of 'null' because of its type in dart, any solutions is appreciated

Tags: flutter, dart

```
void main() {
  
final square = Square(side: 10.0);
 
 print(square.area());
}

abstract class Shape {
 
 double area();

}

class Square implements Shape {

  Square({this.side});

  final double side;

  double area() => side * side;

}
```

Comment: You need to set `side` to a value like 1 or 4.6.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `Square` class has a member declared `final double side;`.  With Dart 2.12 and null-safety enabled, this means that `side` is not allowed to be `null`.

The constructor for your `Square` class is `Square({this.side});`.  It initializes `side` using an *optional* named parameter.  If callers neglect to provide an argument for an optional parameter, it will be initialized to its default value.  If no default value is specified, `null` will be used.  In this case, that therefore contradicts the declaration that `side` cannot be `null`.

There are multiple ways to fix this; pick the one most appropriate for your needs:

- Make the `side` member nullable: `final double? side;`. (Note that this would require adding null-checks everywhere that `side` is used.  This is likely not what you want for your particular case.)
- Provide a non-null default value for `side`: `Square({this.side = 0});`.
- Make `side` non-optional by marking it as a *required* named parameter (`Square({required this.side});`) or as a required positional parameter (`Square(this.side);`).

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
void main() {

final square = Square(10.0);

print(square.area()); }

abstract class Shape {

double area();

}

class Square implements Shape {

Square(this.side);

final double side;

double area() => side * side;

}
```

Did a small change to your code.

Comment: It would help to also explain *what* you changed in the code and *why*.